# Plotting problem for a series of plots

Tags: plotting

```
    g[x_] = 5.91167 + 
       x (8.63312*10^-10 + 
          x (0.0020623 + 
             x (1.35313*10^-9 + 
                x (-2.80417*10^-6 + 
                   x (4.03869*10^-10 + 
                      x (5.32053*10^-9 + 
                        x (3.67271*10^-11 + 
                        x (-1.98534*10^-11 + 
                        x (1.21118*10^-12 + 
                        x (-1.22954*10^-13 + 
                        x (1.50555*10^-14 + 
                        x (-1.21169*10^-15 + 
                        x (6.31704*10^-17 + 
                        x (-2.18852*10^-18 + 
                        x (4.90556*10^-20 + 
                        x (-6.17301*10^-22 + 
                        x (1.52676*10^-24 + (6.42075*10^-26 - 
                        6.38913*10^-28 x) x)))))))))))))))));


u[x_] = 8.07314 + 
   x (-2.324*10^-10 + 
      x (9.86155*10^-6 + 
         x (-3.25595*10^-10 + 
            x (1.59488*10^-10 + 
               x (-8.488*10^-11 + 
                  x (2.72002*10^-11 + 
                    x (-6.65937*10^-12 + 
                    x (1.26859*10^-12 + 
                    x (-1.90257*10^-13 + 
                    x (2.26144*10^-14 + 
                    x (-2.1351*10^-15 + 
                    x (1.5977*10^-16 + 
                    x (-9.4094*10^-18 + 
                    x (4.30444*10^-19 + 
                    x (-1.4968*10^-20 + 
                    x (3.82*10^-22 + 
                    x (-6.7422*10^-24 + (7.34849*10^-26 - 
                    3.72468*10^-28 x) x)))))))))))))))));

d[x_] = 7.38802 + 
   x (-8.88743*10^-8 + 
      x (0.00266487 + 
         x (-1.27894*10^-7 + 
            x (-7.27354*10^-6 + 
               x (-3.40462*10^-8 + 
                  x (3.8489*10^-8 + 
                    x (-2.65374*10^-9 + 
                    x (3.75549*10^-10 + 
                    x (-6.98473*10^-11 + 
                    x (8.02382*10^-12 + 
                    x (-5.90205*10^-13 + 
                    x (2.93816*10^-14 + 
                    x (-1.00062*10^-15 + 
                    x (2.25617*10^-17 + (-3.05627*10^-19 + 
                    1.89199*10^-21 x) x))))))))))))));

b[x_] = 6.69883 + 
   x (6.60446*10^-10 + 
      x (0.0000768412 + 
         x (8.98369*10^-10 + 
            x (-6.10391*10^-9 + 
               x (2.26188*10^-10 + 
                  x (-7.06931*10^-11 + 
                    x (1.7111*10^-11 + 
                    x (-3.20167*10^-12 + 
                    x (4.71874*10^-13 + 
                    x (-5.51587*10^-14 + 
                    x (5.1257*10^-15 + 
                    x (-3.77865*10^-16 + 
                    x (2.19445*10^-17 + 
                    x (-9.90901*10^-19 + 
                    x (3.40446*10^-20 + 
                    x (-8.5928*10^-22 + 
                    x (1.50126*10^-23 + (-1.62111*10^-25 + 
                    8.14743*10^-28 x) x)))))))))))))))));



p1 = Plot[b[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Black Sea"}];
p2 = Plot[d[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Draupner"}];
p3 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Gorm"}];
p4 = Plot[u[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"Ucluelet"}];

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

Is it possible that these functions, which are so dissimilar, are equal?

The plot shows only one plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different:

```
Plot[{g[x], u[x], d[x], b[x]}, {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

You can see this also analytically by e.g.:

```
g[x] - u[x] // Chop // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just change your last `Show`command to

```
Show[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]